# i want a javascript for drag and drop which replaces the dragged data when they are dropped

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am here using a simple java script for drag and drop
the script is

```
$(function() {
  $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
    revert: true
  });

  $( ".draggable" ).draggable({
    connectToSortable: "#sortable",
    helper: "clone",
    revert: "invalid",
  });

  $( "ul, li " ).disableSelection();
});
```

But I want to make a application which will show some images which can be dragged,
But when that image will dropped to the droppable area than it will show different contents regarding to the image, this contents could be anything like plaintext ,images, links etc. and they will come through my php databse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a method "receive( event, ui )" that you should use to do this behaviour.

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
        revert: true,
        receive : function(event, ui) {
            $(ui.item).replaceWith($('<div>').text('blabla'));
        }
    });

    $( ".draggable" ).draggable({
        connectToSortable: "#sortable",
        helper: "clone",
        revert: "invalid",

    });
    $( "ul, li " ).disableSelection();
});
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for your response.. but can you give it with an example? i am a noob in js, i am a php person

Comment: yes it is working, but that replaces the draggable content , i want to change the content on droppable site, for ex, I drag my photograph to droppable area than it could show my name rather than my photo..somethng like that

Comment: sorry I can't access jsfiddle from where I am. Maybe it's the helper : clone that is causing your problem.

Comment: i used another javascript,, which is working like a charm,and please can you help me out this?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13512186/give-unique-ids-to-dragged-html-contents-after-they-are-dropped